# Why doesn't console.log show the result in the console using VS Code?

Tags: javascript

If I use codepen, the code works and shows the calculated result in the console. If I use visual studio code, and view the page using the live server, or open index.html manually, I get the error "ReferenceError: calc() is not defined" when I click calculate.

Why is this?

Edited to add - script has been moved inside the body but the code still doesn't work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lS1WE.png)

```js
function calc() {
    var a = parseInt(document.querySelector('#value1').value);
    var b = parseInt(document.querySelector('#value2').value);
    var op = document.querySelector('#operator').value;
    var calculate;

    if (op == 'add') {
        calculate = a + b;
    } else if (op == 'min') {
        calculate = a - b;
    } else if (op == 'div') {
        calculate = a / b;
    } else if (op == 'mul') {
        calculate = a * b;
    }

    console.log(calculate);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        Value 1: <input type="text" id="value1">
        Value 2: <input type="text" id="value2">
        Operator: 
        <select id="operator">
            <option value="add">Add</option>
            <option value="min">Minus</option>
            <option value="div">Divide</option>
            <option value="mul">Multiply</option>
        </select>
        <button type="button" onclick="calc()">Calculate</button>

    </form>
    
</body>
<script scr="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Your script tag is outside the body element, put it before `</body>`

Comment: ^^ in addition to that, you have `scr` instead of `src`. It needs to be `src` (**s**ou**rc**e).

Comment: scr instead of scr?

Comment: I've moved the script tag inside of  </body> and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Spelling mistake - "src" not "scr"

Answer (score -1):

The script should be within the body element at the end of ending tag, it is the best practice. If you would put the ''script within head element, it would load the javascript before the content. -The Best practice is to load it after the content is loaded.

Comment: That doesn't solve this his issue since he is using inline click handlers. But even if he used Javascript event listener he could  have bound those from the header by listening to the `DOMContentLoaded` event. Your answer should at best have been a comment.